# Cannot delete symbolic links of Python in MacOS BigSur

Tags: python, macos, permissions, uninstallation, permission-denied

I've tried to completely delete Python vers 3.9, that I've installed (following the instructions I found online) but when I try to delete the symbolic links through Terminal I get the error "Permission denied".

This is the string I've used in Terminal: find /usr/local/bin -lname '../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/*' -delete

Comment: That's a little too automated to tell exactly what's going on. Try running it again with the `-delete` removed, so it just prints the locations of the symlinks it finds. Then, examine their permissions and the permissions of the folder(s) they're in.

Comment: Hi Gordon, since I've found the path of the folder in which they are (/usr/local/bin), can't I directly delete the files from the folder?

Comment: Probably, but it depends on the permissions on them and on /usr/local/bin itself. Did you check those?

Comment: Yes, I can delete them confirming the permissions to the pc.
But I'm not sure if I have to delete all the files concerning Python 3, since I just upgraded to MacOS BigSur. Do you know if in BigSur there is Python 3 already installed, or there's only Python 2 and I can delete all concerning version 3 (without risking any problem)?